# Why can't we have a 'Trash button' next to the titles on the lists?

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-close, downvotes

The *Newest* question list should have a combo 'down-vote and close-vote' *Trash* button so that titles that are immediately detected as garbage, (e.g. *Developers need your precious opinion*; yes, I did open it for a laugh and it was indeed utter rubbish for Stack Overflow) can be relegated to delete queues more quickly.

It would be great to get up in the morning and serially click all the C 'linked-list' titles to trash them, (because all of them are debugging-slave requests with rubbish code, single-letter 'i,j,k' variables and no debugging effort applied).  It would save a huge amount of time.  Similarly 'i++ + ++i' etc.

I promise that I would never misuse such functionality by trashing all the PHP questions.

Comment: Related Meta request: [Up/Down buttons in question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153662)

Answer (score 16):

**Always** look at the full question before you decide to trash it. Summaries rarely can convey the true worth of a question.

As such, voting and moderation should strictly be restricted to the question page itself, not to the question list.

Comment: Summaries often can convey the true worth of a question, assuming 'worth' can go negative.  I mean ''Developers need your precious opinion' - what are the chances that it's going to be a good question?

Comment: Low. But check the content to confirm it.

Comment: TBH though, I didn't really expect much of a positive response from my featurerequest:)   It's more of a rant against the acceleration in rubbish questions, even over the last few days.

Comment: @Bart 'Low'?  It's got 'Opinion' in the title:)

Comment: @MartinJames here's an [example](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/177875/revisions "check revisions history"): a question with definitely crappy original title ("Why did Git become so popular?") and reasonable request to explain a concrete objective historical fact inside